# How to create Android app WITHOUTH action bar?

Tags: eclipse, android-actionbar

I can not create an android app with an SDK < 14 (4.0) because all of the templates (including the so-called "Blank") include the "Action Bar", which is a 14+ feature.

How do I create an app WITHOUT an action bar?  Does somebody have an old template for Blank without an Action Bar?

Comment: Can you include more details about the SDK you are using?

Comment: There are a ton of SDKs, ranging from 8 up to 21.  Because I have some old devices, I want to target Android 3.2 (SDK 13).  This is not possible because even the blank template now includes an "Action Bar".  Apparently the way we are supposed to deal with this is to use the automatically generated appcompat_v7 ... but that does not work ... at least not as generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the [Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html) object and using the method [hide()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#hide()) you will be able to hide it.

```
final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
```

And from the documentation:

> Instead of calling this function directly, you can also cause an
>   ActionBar using the overlay feature to hide through
>   View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN. Hiding the ActionBar through this
>   system UI flag allows you to more seamlessly hide it in conjunction
>   with other screen decorations

Hope it helps

Comment: Actually, that is the opposite of help ... unless I am misunderstanding something.

This "ActionBar" thing seems to be preventing me from targeting with an SDK < 14. But all of the templates for new apps include the ActionBar.

How do I create an app for earlier versions (i.e. NO action bar)? Is that even possible anymore?